# How to auto change numbering of series of Q's on a survey page based on selecting yes/no ans

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a survey that is written using DIV elements instead of traditions TABLE method.

Issue is: I have to auto number the question numbers on the page. There is one questions that asks for a 'yes' or 'no' answer and if the user answers 'yes' then there are few more questions that show on the page and if the user selects 'no' then they won't appear. Also, there is a question that says to select multiple options that apply to the user, and based on these checkboxes (or selections), there are few more Q's that show up on the page.

Need to auto-number in sequence according to the questions that display on the page.

This is something close to what I want to acheive - http://jsfiddle.net/3RZWt/8/ but with DIVs , NO TABLE Layout. So, instead of deleting option, I have yes/no radio buttons and some checkboxes that show additional questions.

```
<div class="form-control">
<label><span class="question-number">1</span>. Who:</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control" style="display:none;">
<label><span class="question-number">2</span>. What:</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control">
<label><span class="question-number">3</span>. When:</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control">
<label><span class="question-number">4</span>. Where:</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control">
<label><span class="question-number">5</span>. Why:</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Wouldn't the 'sub-questions' be numbered like 3a, 3b etc? That would be the logical progression.

Comment: No, the whole survey has like total 24 questions and some of them display on screen according to the selections based on selections from Q's that have checkboxes. Let me compile the code and add it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple jQuery selector and then iterate over the results, like so:

```js
function autonumber(){
  $.each($('.question-number:visible'), function(i, elem){
    $(elem).text(i + 1);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-control">
<label><span class="question-number">1</span>. Who:</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control" style="display:none;">
<label><span class="question-number">1</span>. What:</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control">
<label><span class="question-number">1</span>. When:</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control">
<label><span class="question-number">1</span>. Where:</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control">
<label><span class="question-number">1</span>. Why:</label>
</div>

<button onclick="autonumber()">Auto Number</button>
```

Comment: This works for sorting once the page displays. In a scenario where there are additional questions popping up based on some conditional selections aren't being numbered in sequence. This solution only works the first time it loads and does not apply when there is logic going on the page. Any tips on that? I am trying to compile and example but something doesn't work in Fiddle  :)

Comment: Changing the question numbers is going to be a very confusing ux... But you can just call the autonumber function again and it will reorder everything.

Comment: Thanks, so much JDB. I did tweak it a bit, but worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

Used the order(); function to call after each radio button and checkbox event trigger (after show and hide, both the events). Worked like charm!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        order();

        function order() {

            (function renumberQuestions() {
                $('.question-number:visible').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).text(index + 1);
                });
            })();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

using same principle than in the example seems even less work, no? :

```
body {
    counter-reset: count;
}

.question-number {
    counter-increment: count;
}

.question-number:after {
    content: counter(count);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works too! But, sometimes it gave me problem in IE8 browser. This was the first solution that came to my mind though!